# Perl: reading all files of a directory, error: no such file or directory

Tags: perl

I am working in Perl on the very beginning stages of a program to read all files in a directory matching a certain pattern then parsing each of them. It works if the code is in the same directory as the files, but I would like it to be able to work no matter where the program is located, as long as the path in the program is correct. Can anyone help me out on how to do this?

Here is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl5.16.2

my $dir = '/my/path/';

opendir(files, $dir) or die ("The directory could not be opened: $!");
@files = grep { /^jhu*/ && -f "$dir/$_" } readdir(files);
closedir(files);

foreach $file (@files) {

    open(file, $file) or die "$!";

    while(<file>) {

    $line = $_;
    chomp($line);

    @cols = split(/\t/, $line);

    print "$cols[4]\n";
    }
}

close(file);
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can use strict and warnings pragmas to improve your code

Comment: There are two core ways to list the contents of a file system directory, One is to use [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html)
 as you have done, and the other is [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)
, which implements something like the command-line wildcard semantics. Both of these will include directories as well as files indiscriminately. `readdir` has the additional problem that it will return the current and parent pseudo-directories `.` and `..` as well as any real content, and will provide just the names without any associated path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to prepend the directory to the elements of `@files` afterwards.

```
foreach $file (@files) {
    open(my $fh, "$dir/$file") or die "Can't open $dir/$file: $!";
    while (<$fh>) { ... }
    # ...
}
```

Notice I've also used a lexical filehandle instead of opening the bareword `file`, which is frowned upon for various reasons.

Comment: Wow. Duh. Thank you! And thanks for the tip about the filehandle. Perl is a whole new world to me.